# Using reflective optics concepts to focus gas pressure in a vacuum

Tags: optics, vacuum, molecular-dynamics

At very low vacuum pressures the bulk behaviour of molecules can be approximated by non interacting particles bouncing off of the chamber walls:

For an monotonic molecule such as He with perfect symmetry the incident and reflected angles are equal but opposite either side of the surface normal (conservation of momentum) analogous to a photon being reflected off of a mirror.

My understanding is that for polyatomic molecules that lack symmetry the angle of deflection would be independent of any effects from its rotation (based on independence of conservation of linear and angular momentum) and still follow the same behaviour as the monotonic case.

While the angles would not be exact due to surface roughness and effects from where on the surface of the rotating non-symmetrical molecule happens to strike the surface I presume that statistically there would be some correlation.

If the above assumptions are correct then it would follow that the shape of a vacuum chamber could be designed using parabolic shapes and other concepts borrowed from reflective optics to concentrate stray gas molecules at a focal point where the local pressure would increase to levels where a pump normally considered only for roughing could still be viable.

In effect the vacuum in the chamber would be magnified.

[Edit]
As pointed out in the comment below the molecules are hitting at random angles so your standard parabolic mirror shape isn't going to achieve anything. So the problem now becomes how is scattered light able to be collected in nonimaging optics - perhaps borrowing from the shape of a [compound parabolic concentrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonimaging_optics#Compound_parabolic_concentrator).

Comment: Reflection on a wall will only approximately conserve linear momentum and more importantly will certainly couple angular and linear momentum strongly! Angular momentum is only conserved in isotropic situations, isotropy is broken by the wall. Also, for complex molecules the reflection will not be elastic as low lying internal degrees of freedom will be excited (on might say phonons). (The phonon degrees of freedom of the wall will also contribute).

Comment: Curved reflective optics can be used to concentrate light from a specific source.  I don't see how that concept can be applied to a low pressure vacuum in which the incident direction of the molecules is completely random.  Your idea might work if a specific source, i.e. a leak, can be identified though.

Comment: Thanks Chris Mueller for pointing out a crucial floor in my logic! Back to the drawing board...